# Background image not showing up in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

So I have this code (in http://localhost/index.html):

```
<input type="button" value="Yea" class="button" />
```

with the CSS style (in http://localhost/min/css.css):

```
.button {
    background-image: url(../images/button.gif);
}
```

However, the background doesn't show up in any version of Internet Explorer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does it help to put the url in quotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE has [known issues](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322240) with the `background-image` property. See what happens when you use `background` instead.

```
.button {
    background: white url('../images/button.gif') no-repeat top;
}
```

Or alternatively, you could try

```
<input type="image" src="../images/button.gif" value="Yea" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.button{
      background: transparent url('../images/backrgound.jpg') no-repeat top center;
}
```

CSS Standard
background : **color *URL*** **repeat-section** and **position**

**JPEG Images**

Check whether images are of JPEG2000, if yes, then open any image editor and save it again with proper jpeg extension